# Dynamically Increasing Height of form in Extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using SuperBoxSelect as one of my components in a form. As the height of the SuperBoxSelect increases when we select data, I want the height of the form to increase/decrease respectively.
Is there any property which help me achieve this?

```
{
    xtype:'container',
    layout:'vbox',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'boxselect',
        closable:true,
        height:40,
        //fieldLabel:'Discipline',
        width:240,
        displayField: 'fullName',
        valueField: 'userID',
        queryMode: 'remote',
        forceSelection: true,
        store : store
    }
```

Comment: How is the height of the form defined? For example, if your form is in a window component, you'll have to increase the height of the window to allow the form to be displayed fully.

Comment: My form is not in a window and i have tried different value for height  attribute. Even when i make it a comment there is no change in height.

Comment: Lets see the code that contains this. I might be able to help then.

Comment: @forgivenson thanks for taking interest.It got done by layout:'anchor',anchorSize:'x%y%'

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out